Connecting standalone LWR SPA and Apex Class to get access token
I have created standalone LWR SPA with command npm init lwr@latest.
And also I have created SFDX class to create Apex class and deploy the class.
To use the API, I fetch the API like this:
const response = await fetch(
        `${myEndPoint}`,
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ data: data }),
        }
      ).then((response) => {
        const accessToken = response.json();
        return accessToken;
      });

However, the calling API is rejected with 401 error without Authorization. The API is built to get access token, but cannot run without access token.
Moreover, in the Apex class, I use method Auth.AuthToken.getAccessToken.
String accessToken = Auth.AuthToken.getAccessToken(authProviderId, providerName);
return accessToken;

authProviderId and providerName are the value that found at Salesforce org > setup > Auth.Providers > Auth.Provider ID field and Name field.
However, the accessToken value is shown as null.

Where in the docs did you see a suggestion that my standalone SPA will magically generate a Salesforce-specific authorization token

@identigral It does not magically generate. I asked,  in LWR SPA with Apex Class, whether I can get the access token that is generated by salesforce org or not. Specifically by using getAccessToken Apex method.

Auth.AuthToken.getAccessToken is used in Salesforce (Apex) to get the token for access to an external system that has been authorized via OAuth. To log in to Salesforce, you must log in to Salesforce.
The typical way modern apps log in is to Authorize Apps with OAuth. In summary, you'll create a Connected App, configure it for OAuth access, then use the Client Id (and optionally Client Secret, depending on the flow) to log in to Salesforce. For a SPA, you probably want to use the User-Agent Flow.

To get access token, I need to authorize app with OAuth. Thank you. I thought it is possible that using Apex class which is defined as global with sharing class in LWR SPA is possible in LWR SPA without token. Is this correct that I need to authorize with OAuth then get access token to access salesforce custom data and other resources of salesforce org in LWR SPA?

@user149845 You just need to authorize with OAuth, which will give you the access token you need. You don't need the Apex code, because the Auth.AuthToken.getAccessToken method is only for accessing external systems with OAuth.

In that case, the access token is time-limited, then I need to refresh the access token. The access token is generated, but it will be invalid if I do not use for a while, then need to get new access token. Is there any code-base example to get authorized via codes?
